# T3 lamp in Harbor Breeze ceiling fan issue

Tags: ceiling-fan

Ceiling fan light went out. After a struggle to remove the globe, I discovered it needs a special bulb. Geez, I cannot believe my luck! Anyway, after researching, I discovered it uses a T3 100W 120v 78mm halogen lamp. I have tried three different manufacturers and cannot get the lamp to work. I tested the continuity of the original lamp (even though I could plainly see the broken element) and the replacement lamp. I have tried searching the internet up on the side and down the other without a hint of this being an issue. I found this site and thought before I start tearing things apart, I would ask this question. I'm hoping somebody else has had a similar problem or can point out how I may have missed the obvious.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add pictures of the socket and old bulb? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I find the contacts need burnishing in those type of lamps sometimes, many times I have found damaged wiring due to the high heat these lamps produce, since you have tried several lamps I would check the contacts with a meter to make sure there is 120v on the pins, when the lamp failed it may have damaged the wiring, you already have lamps but I have been changing over to led they are expensive but in our portable work lights they don’t produce the heat and can handle being bumped better than the halogen ones.  But check your wiring , and make sure not to touch the lamp, if you do clean it.